# Pause video on slide in slider.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I'm building a video gallery using slider.io and I want that the video pauses if a user goes to next slide/video. I'm trying to use onSlideChangeStart and onSlideChangeEnd function however it is not working.

code:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            centeredSlides: true,
            paginationClickable: true,
            spaceBetween: 0,
            nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
            loop: true,
            onSlideChangeStart: function (swiper) {
                $('.swiper-button-next').click(function () {
                    $('video')[0].pause();
                });


            },
            onSlideChangeEnd: function (swiper) {
                $('.swiper-button-next').click(function () {
                    $('video')[0].pause();
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: Check below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I found a solution for this by using the below method


var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            centeredSlides: true,
            paginationClickable: true,
            spaceBetween: 0,
            nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
            loop: true,
            onSlideChangeStart: function (swiper) {
                $('.swiper-slide').find('video').each(function() {
                    this.pause();
                });

            },
            onSlideChangeEnd: function (swiper) {
                $('.swiper-slide').find('video').each(function() {
                    this.pause();
                });

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`onSlideChangeStart` and `onSlideChangeEnd` you can check if any `video` is playing in `next` or `prev` slide then pause it.

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rsp34mg/10/)

```
 onSlideChangeStart: function(swiper) {
    if ($('.swiper-slide-next video')[0]) $('.swiper-slide-next video')[0].pause();
    if ($('.swiper-slide-prev video')[0]) $('.swiper-slide-prev video')[0].pause();

  },
  onSlideChangeEnd: function(swiper) {
    if ($('.swiper-slide-next video')[0]) $('.swiper-slide-next video')[0].pause();
    if ($('.swiper-slide-prev video')[0]) $('.swiper-slide-prev video')[0].pause();
  },
```